# determine the series solution to the corresponding roots $2xy''+y'+xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the following question I am trying to determine the series solution to the corresponding roots,

$$2xy''+y'+xy=0$$

I have determined the indicial equation to be,

$$r(2r-1)=0, r=\frac{1}{2}, r=0$$

I have determined the reccurence solution to be,

$$a_n = - \frac{a_{n-2}}{(n+r)[2(n+r)-1]}$$

However I am a little confused how to determine the first series solution which is,

$$y_1(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[ 1 - \frac{x^2}{2\cdot5}+\frac{x^4}{2\cdot4\cdot5\cdot9} - \frac{x^6}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot5\cdot9\cdot13} \right....]$$

I know that $n\geq 2.$

So using $r=\frac{1}{2}$

$$a_2 = -\frac{a_0}{(2+\frac{1}{2})2[(2+\frac{1}{2})-1]}$$

but what is $a_0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is linear. It means that if $y$ is a solution, then so as $cy$ for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus you are free to choose $\color{red}{a_{0}=1}$ and get $y_{1}(x)$. Then a general solution is

$$y(x)=\color{blue}{c_{1}}y_{1}(x)+\color{blue}{c_{2}}y_{2}(x)$$

where $y_{2}$ is the second series solution and $\color{blue}{c_{1}},\color{blue}{c_{2}}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for your help!